# Renaming project output in visual studio using post build event generates error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to rename the project exe output in visual studio 2010.
Following the post 
[Rename project output before being included into Setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420611/rename-project-output-before-being-included-into-setup-project)
I always get the error `The command rename ... exited with code 1`

My command is:

```
rename $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName) newname.exe
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to rename the project exe output in visual studio 2010.

I suggest you go into the project settings and change the output assembly name then. That's going to be far simpler and more reliable than using a post-build event.

It's possible that the fact that your current post-build command has an unmatched double-quote is the problem, but I wouldn't try to fix it - I'd just avoid it.

Comment: For me, this is still coming out as setup.exe despite my assembly name being something else

Comment: @Webnet: Are you should you're not building an installer binary? I've never seen anything automatically create a setup.exe file other than for installers...

Comment: I don't know... This is my first C# app, so maybe I am?  How can I check and/or change it so it comes out as `MyApp.exe`?

Comment: @Webnet: Well what project type have you got? It feels like you should probably start a new question with all the relevant information, to be honest - it's not ideal for a comment thread here.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a correct command for the Post-build event

```
rename "$(TargetPath)" "newname.exe"
```

Comment: The second argument can not be a path. Took me a long time to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Post-Build to execute a Batch file and/or PowerShell script to do whatever you want:

Post-Build cmd:

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" start "Version" /D "$(SolutionDir)" /WAIT Version.bat
```

Version.bat:

```
@powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "%~dp0Version.ps1"

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo ERROR
    pause
) ELSE (echo OK)
```

Version.ps1:

```
# A lot of possibilities here
$scriptDirectory =  [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
```